How to get default light mode in Bulma 1.0 using sass?
I updated to Bulma v1.0 and want to only use the light mode.
I have used both @use and @import for the bulma/sass directory, but this results in the same thing. the website changes themes depending on my system mode. When I manually include only the light.scss, there is no styling when my system is set to dark mode.

change your html element like this:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" data-theme="light" >
<head>
  <title>my page</title>
</head>
<body>
 
</body>
</html>

